# Sequentially stock utilization in sql server

Tags: sql-server

Below is my  order table. and Start number : 300 and last number: 900 given  by customer based on order

```
  declare @Order table
    (
       Id int,
       [From] int,
       [To] int
    )

    Insert Into @Order
    Values 


       (1,100,400),
        (2,401,600),
        (3,601,1000),
        (4,1001,2000),
    Declare @first int=300, @last int=900
```

Required Output:

[image]

Please give a solution. Based on Start and end number   i have to calculate Start and end column

Comment: Please show what you have tried and where you have failed.Also explain the log here. Stackoverflow isn't a free coding service.

Comment: Thanks..i have written below query 
select * from @order WHERE NOT ([from] > [@Last] OR [@To] < first)
But i didnt get how to get  [from] and [to]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Edit - Re-Thunk'd It**

**Example**

```
Declare @Order table(  Id int,[From] int,[To] int )
Insert Into @Order Values 
(1,100,400),
(2,401,600),
(3,601,1000),
(4,1001,2000)

Declare @first int=300, @last int=900

Select A.*
      ,[Start] = case when [From]>@First then [From] else @First end
      ,[End]   = case when @Last <[To] then @Last else [To] end
 From  @Order A
 Where [To] between @First and @Last
    or @Last between [From] and [To]
```

**Returns**

```
Id  From    To      Start   End
1   100     400     300     400
2   401     600     401     600
3   601     1000    601     900
```

Comment: thanks @John Cappelletti but Declare [@first] int=500, [@last] int=900
for this case not works

Comment: @Ljt Your right, lack of imagination on my part.  One moment

Comment: @Ljt Updated the WHERE